# Unable to access Key-Vault using Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azureportal

I have inherited a Azure project and is struggling with accessing some of the information in it. There are multiple keyvault which I need to get into, but I dont have access, and I dont understand why as I am the project owner. I am signed in as the user with the OK profile picture.

[image]

If I go to Keys or secrets I get the following error:
The operation "List" is not enabled in this key vault's access policy.

Network access is set to "All networks"

So I go to access policies to give myself access.
There I click the "Add new" Button.
This brings me to the screen where I can set up permissions and add a principal. When I search for my user there I can not find it. Searching for users which already are in the access control list also returns nothing.

[image]
The "searching..." status never disappears, but I do get a red line around the email after a while.

How do I get access to a keyvault using the portal?

Comment: In the question, `So I go to access control to give myself access.` , I think you go to the `Access policies` to give yourself access? And you cannot find yourself there?

Comment: I updated the question to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: I see you have two users with the OK profile picture but with different scopes, which user do you sign in ?

Comment: They have the same email. I think its just a case that I am added twice on this resource. Once as a owner and once explicitly on this resource

Comment: What about removing one user with `this resource` scope, then sign in with another user, try it again?

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue, even if you are the guest user in the tenant, you are the owner of the subscription, you will be able to add yourself in the access policies. Maybe try to change a browser to have a try?

Comment: I tried that, but I still cant find myself when I search. Even tried using the Azure App

Comment: Is there any error message when you search? any typo?

Comment: Sometimes the line around the textbox goes red after a while, but the text never changes. It's like the search is stuck. No error messages. I have tried multiple times, with different users. I never get any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your key vault was moved (with the subscription) from another Azure AD tenant and kept its binding to said tenant. So you might want to associate it with the new tenant as described in this MS article: [Change a key vault tenant ID after a subscription move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-subscription-move-fix).

```
$subscriptionId = <Your subscription ID>
$keyVaultName = <Key Vault name>

Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
$vaultResourceId = (Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $keyVaultName).ResourceId
$vault = Get-AzResource –ResourceId $vaultResourceId -ExpandProperties
$vault.Properties.TenantId = (Get-AzContext).Tenant.TenantId
$vault.Properties.AccessPolicies = @()
Set-AzResource -ResourceId $vaultResourceId -Properties $vault.Properties
```

**Note**: security principals (users and applications) in the old Azure AD tenant will lose their access to the key vault after this operation. So if by any chance, there is an application deployed in your subscription, which uses application ID (and secret) registered in the old tenant, you'll need to make a new app registration in your Azure AD, give it permissions to the key vault and redeploy the app with the new credentials.